# Mock Object and Interface

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I'm a newbie in Unit Test with Mock Object. I use EasyMock. I try to understand this example:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public interface ExchangeRate {

    double getRate(String inputCurrency, String outputCurrency) throws IOException;

}
```

---

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class Currency {

    private String units;
    private long amount;
    private int cents;


    public Currency(double amount, String code) {
        this.units = code;
        setAmount(amount);
    }

    private void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = new Double(amount).longValue();
        this.cents = (int) ((amount * 100.0) % 100);
    }

    public Currency toEuros(ExchangeRate converter) {
        if ("EUR".equals(units)) return this;
        else {
            double input = amount + cents/100.0;
            double rate;
            try {
                rate = converter.getRate(units, "EUR");
                double output = input * rate;
                return new Currency(output, "EUR");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Currency) {
            Currency other = (Currency) o;
            return this.units.equals(other.units)
                    && this.amount == other.amount
                    && this.cents == other.cents;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return amount + "." + Math.abs(cents) + " " + units;
    }

}
```

---

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CurrencyTest extends TestCase {

    public void testToEuros() throws IOException {
        Currency testObject = new Currency(2.50, "USD");
        Currency expected = new Currency(3.75, "EUR");
        ExchangeRate mock = EasyMock.createMock(ExchangeRate.class);
        EasyMock.expect(mock.getRate("USD", "EUR")).andReturn(1.5);
        EasyMock.replay(mock);
        Currency actual = testObject.toEuros(mock);
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

}
```

So, i wonder how to Currency use ExchangeRate in `toEuros(..)` method.

```
rate = converter.getRate(units, "EUR");
```

The behavior of `getRate(..)` method is not specified because `ExchangeRate` is an interface.

```
/********************************************************************************/
```

So I try do myself example. Following is my codes:

```
/**
 *Interface to access data
 */
public interface Dao {
    public boolean getEntityById(int id) throws SQLException;
}

/**
 *Business class do something in business layer
 */
public class Bussiness {
    private Dao dao;

    public Dao getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(Dao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public boolean doSomeThing(int id) throws SQLException {
        if(dao.getEntityById(id)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Bussiness b = new Bussiness();
        b.doSomeThing(3);
    }
}


package tunl;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    /**
     * This is my unit Test
     */
    @Test
    public class MyUnitTest {
        private Bussiness bussiness;
        private Dao mock;

        @BeforeTest
        public void setUp() {
            bussiness = new Bussiness();
            mock = EasyMock.createMock(Dao.class);// interface not class
            bussiness.setDao(mock);
        }

        public void testDoSomeThing() throws SQLException {
            EasyMock.expect(mock.getEntityById(3)).andReturn(true);
            EasyMock.replay(mock);
            Assert.assertTrue(bussiness.doSomeThing(3));
        }
    }
```

So, The unit Tess run correctly

But when i want to run main method in Business Object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
            Bussiness b = new Bussiness();
            b.doSomeThing(3);
}
```

I have to add the constructor for Business.

```
public Bussiness() {
     dao = new DaoImpl();
}
```

So, my business class is:

```
package tunl;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Bussiness {
    private Dao dao;

    public Bussiness() {
        dao = new DaoImpl();
    }
    public Dao getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(Dao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public boolean doSomeThing(int id) throws SQLException {
        if(dao.getEntityById(id)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Bussiness b = new Bussiness();
        b.doSomeThing(3);
    }
}
```

Also I have to implement Dao interface:

```
package tunl;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DaoImpl implements Dao {

    @Override
    public boolean getEntityById(int id) throws SQLException {
        if(id == 3) {
            System.out.println("System input 3 ");
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("You have to input  3 ");
        return false;
    }

}
```

In design, you always create interface for all of the classes which will be tested (like DaoImpl) !!!
So is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

EasyMock creates a *mock object* based on the interface. The mock object implements all the methods of the interface and for those methods you specify (e.g. with `expect`), it "replays" the specified behaviour when they are called.

When a mock object is created, it is in *recording mode*. The line

```
EasyMock.expect(mock.getRate("USD", "EUR")).andReturn(1.5);
```

specifies that when `mock.getRate` is called with the given parameters, it shall return 1.5 . Then the object is put into *replay mode* with the call

```
EasyMock.replay(mock);
```

All this is explained in more details in the [documentation](http://easymock.org/EasyMock2_5_2_Documentation.html).

**Update:** to your comment - `Currency` is passed an instance of `ExchangeRate` here:

```
public Currency toEuros(ExchangeRate converter) { ... }
```

All it cares is that it gets an object implementing that interface, so that

```
rate = converter.getRate(units, "EUR");
```

can be called. The test method, then, passes the mock object it created to the currency object:

```
Currency actual = testObject.toEuros(mock);
```

Hope this helps; if not, maybe you could read some introductory text on OOP, interfaces and inheritance to get a better understanding.

In the code example in your answer, the `Dao` object should be passed to `Bussiness` rather than created internally, since the latter effectively prevents unit testing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Bussiness b = new Bussiness();
        b.setDao(new DaoImpl());
        b.doSomeThing(3);
}
```

You could also add a parameterized constructor to `Bussiness` to make the initialization in one step instead of two.

Comment: Thanks mr Péter Török,
The interface's method are specified in CurrencyTest by EasyMock. 
But I still don't understand that How to Currency uses Interface's methods(not CurrencyTest). 
Because you always have to use interface in EasyMock so how to business classes response.

Comment: Now, I understood. My weakness is that I don't know how to pass DaoImpl to Business. And the Mock always go together with Interface.
Thank you again and sorry about my mistakes.